# I made something in my code and I am not sure how to use it

Tags: vb.net

First I have to say that I'm new to `vb.net`. I had an idea to make a tic-tac toe game and the same time I have to practice on using the OOP. First I created 9 objects as buttons. I Guess I will drop down the code and ask the question.

```
Public Class XO
    Friend WithEvents BT As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    Public value As Integer
    Public index As Integer
    Public line1 As Integer
    Public line2 As Integer
    Public clicks As Integer = 1
    Public Shared Turn As String = "X"
    Public x As String = "X"


    Public Sub New(ByVal val As Integer, ByVal indx As Integer)
        Me.value = val
        Me.index = indx
        Me.BT = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        Me.BT.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 50)

        If indx <= 3 Then
            Me.BT.Location = New System.Drawing.Point((index - 1) * 50, 0)
        ElseIf indx <= 6 Then
            Me.BT.Location = New System.Drawing.Point((index - 4) * 50, 50)
        ElseIf indx <= 9 Then
            Me.BT.Location = New System.Drawing.Point((index - 7) * 50, 100)
        End If
        line1 = setline1(Me.index)
        line2 = setline2(Me.index)


    End Sub


    Public Function setline1(ByVal index As Integer)
        Select Case index
            Case 1, 2, 3
                Return 1
            Case 4, 5, 6
                Return 2
            Case 7, 8, 9
                Return 3
        End Select
    End Function
    Public Function setline2(ByVal index As Integer)
        Select Case index
            Case 1, 4, 7
                Return 1
            Case 2, 5, 8
                Return 2
            Case 3, 6, 9
                Return 3
        End Select
    End Function


    Private Sub BTclick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BT.Click
        'If BT.Text = "" Then
        '    If Turn = "O" Then
        '        BT.Text = "O"
        '        Turn = "X"
        '    ElseIf Turn = "X" Then
        '        BT.Text = "X"
        '        Turn = "O"
        '    End If
        'End If
        BT.Text = "X"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Simply my question is :  I have created buttons places as index so as you see in the code 1,2,3 return 1 as line 1. I want to tell the program that if line 1 has 3 buttons contain String "X" then msgbox("X is the winner")

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a generic list so you can more easily refer to your buttons. Try the below implementation to see if it helps. If you want to have your own object as each place like you are trying to do then you just create a list of those objects. Either way, you need to keep track of the objects (as a collection).

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim buttons As List(Of Button) = New List(Of Button)()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Create the 9 buttons
        For i = 0 To 8 Step 1
            Dim btn As Button = New Button
            btn.Name = "Button" & i.ToString()
            btn.Text = ""
            'Do what you need to do with you button like placement and such.
            'Try like this.
            '0|1|2
            '3|4|5
            '6|7|8

            Select Case i
                Case 0
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
                Case 1
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
                Case 2
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
                Case 3
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
                Case 4
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
                Case 5
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
                Case 6
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
                Case 7
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
                Case 8
                    btn.Location = New Point(1, 1)
            End Select

            'Do what you need to do with you button like placement and such.
            'All buttons should be handled by the same event handler for simplicity.
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ButtonHandler
            buttons.Add(btn)
        Next


    End Sub


    Public Sub CheckFirstLine()
        'Check for a winner
        'If you placed your buttons like this.
        '0|1|2
        '3|4|5
        '6|7|8
        'then
        'You could handle the check of the first line like this

        If buttons.Item(0).Text = "X" And buttons.Item(1).Text = "X" And buttons.Item(2).Text = "X" Then
            MessageBox.Show("X Wins")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim myButton = CType(sender, Button)
        If myButton.Text <> "" Then
            'Can't play here.
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'Whose turn is it?
            myButton.Text = "X"
        End If
        CheckFirstLine()
    End Sub

End Class
```